# Bufferoverflow 64 bit linux

Tags: 64-bit, shellcode

I'm resolving an exercise where I have to exploit a bufferoverflow to spawn a shell. I got the offset, the payload and so on and via gdb i can see that the shell starts: "process 4854 is executing new program: /usr/bin/dash", but immediately the process is killed, killing the shell itself.

I tried to prevent the exit in any possible way. I saw that the cat command can be used (like this cat | ./program), but i cannot use it in gdb. Without gdb i cannot pass the asked value of the program to reach the vulnerable function (the code does not implement argv in the main). Any help?

Answer (score 0):

The most recent operating systems have some protections against attacks like buffer overflows. In this type of attack, the goal is to manipulate the return value with the memory address of your shell. Some operating systems prevent the execution of code in the buffer by terminating the process. Another protection method involves placing a barrier code between the return value and the variable space. If this value is overwritten, the operating system terminates the process.

I've practiced on Ubuntu 7.04 because this version is vulnerable to these kinds of attacks. Perhaps you could try it as well. Hope this is helpful!